# Best way to Call API in controller?

Tags: loops, cakephp, controller

In Message **Model**, I have

id/Subject/Comment/SenderID/RecipientID

So in Message **Controller**

```
public function index(){

 $msgs = $this->Message->find();
 $this->set('msgs', $msgs);
}
```

In Message **view**

```
foreach ($msgs as $msg)

 echo ...

 
endforeach
```

BUT instead of outputting sender ID and recipient ID, I want to be able to get the username via an API which has already been set up, http://example.com/userid/1, it will return the username in a JSON.

I know it's a bad practice to do this in view, but can you suggest how should I do this in controller?

Answer (score 2):

Create a model for your API calls, tell cake not to look for a db table for it and have the function with the logic to pull the username there.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class MyAPI extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false;

    public function getUserNameForID(Int $id = null) {
        //Your logic here
        return $userName;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you need to load the MyAPI model and pass it your data recursivly

```
$this->loadModel('MyAPI');

foreach (...) {
    ...
    $userName = $this->MyAPI->getUserNameForID($userID);
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 in particular for "create a model" - know that you can use a datasource [like this one](https://github.com/nodesagency/CakePHP-Rest-Datasource) to make your model act like any other model (just a lot slower - since requests will be external =) ).